# Can't upload files using $_FILES in php

Tags: php

I am not able to upload files using the following script.
I don't know what is wrong with that or i have to configure my php.ini. Please help...
Here is my HTML code:

```
<form method="get" action="review" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form">
<input type="file" name="attachment" />
</div>

<input type="submit" class="button" value="Upload file" />
</form>
```

My php script on /review/index.php is:

```
if(isset($_GET["attachment"])){
    $file_name = $_FILES["attachment"]['name'];
    $random_digit=rand(0000,9999);
    $new_file_name=$random_digit.$file_name;
    $url="/attachment/".$new_file_name;

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $url)) 
 {
    echo"file uploaded";

    $attachment='<h3>Attachment</h3><img src="/images/glyphicons_062_paperclip.png" />  <a href="/attachment/'.$_GET["attachment"].'">'.$_GET["attachment"].'</a>';
    }
```

I am getting error like:

**Undefined index: attachment in C:\xampp\htdocs\view question\review answer\index.php on line 13**

I dont know where i am doing wrong please help....
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You're missing your closing } aren't you?

Comment: Change all the $_GET to $_POST, the file data is sent via POST body not as query string.

Comment: Thanks all of you i changed it to $post and now it is working..

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
<form method="get"
```

with:

```
<form method="POST"
```

Answer (score 0):

File type field value you are sending is not available in GET REQUEST..

Try changing this(line 13):

```
if(isset($_GET["attachment"])){
```

to this:

```
if(isset($_FILES["attachment"])){
```

Answer (score 0):

Method = "GET" should be replaced with POST. GET should be used to get information from the Server and POST to post something on the server. Use GET only for things that do not change anything on the server.

Moreover, the URL is limited to about 2000 characters so squeezing a file in a URL is not a very good idea. File can also URL encoded so do not use GET.

Answer (score 0):

First you change

```
<form method="get"
```

to

```
<form method="post"
```

and then change global variables

```
$_GET['attachment']
```

to

```
$_POST['attachment']
```